# Function takes a void pointer of a structure and passes on a pointer to its member to another function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Yes the title is as confusing as I am confused. The code may help show what I am trying to achieve;

In a function, I pass this;

```
RESTOUCH_POINT_STRUCT stConvertPoint;

stConvertPoint.usX = astLCDPoints[0].usX;
stConvertPoint.usY = astLCDPoints[0].usY;

Driver_Control((DRIVER_STRUCT*)pstResTouch->pstDisplay, CMD_CONVERT_POINT_TO_ORIENTATION, &stConvertPoint);
```

The receiving driver function, needs to accept the address of `stConvertPoint` as a void pointer, and then cast it to obtain pointers to its members `usX`, and `usY`. This then gets passed to an internal function, which changes the value of `usX` and `usY`.

```
DRIVER_RETURN ILI9328_Control(DRIVER_STRUCT *pstDriver_, USHORT usID_, void *pvData_)
{
...
case CMD_CONVERT_POINT_TO_ORIENTATION:
{
  DRAW_POINT_STRUCT* pstPoint = (DRAW_POINT_STRUCT*)pvData_;
  USHORT *pusX;
  USHORT *pusY;

  pusX = (USHORT*)pstPoint->usX;
  pusY = (USHORT*)pstPoint->usY;

  ILI9328_ConvertPointOrientation(pstDriver_, pusX, pusY);
}
break;
```

Assuming this all works, the values of `stConvertPoint.usX` and `stConvertPoint.usY` should now be different in the calling function.

Is this at all possible? Pointers and references always get me horribly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (by the naming convention) that the `usX` and `usY` members are simply `unsigned short` (they aren't pointers), then you *do not* want:

```
pusX = (USHORT*)pstPoint->usX;
pusY = (USHORT*)pstPoint->usY;
```

Which will create pointers that are invalid and useless.

Instead you want:

```
pusX = &pstPoint->usX;
pusY = &pstPoint->usY;
```

which are pointers to the two members of the structure.